# How to remove dropMenu caret in Bootsfaces?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, jsf, bootsfaces

I am using *BootsFaces* for my responsive UI rendering in JSF project. Everything looks cool that comes up with *BootsFaces*. UI design is much easier with this. But at the same time I find there might be not enough flexibility to customize the UI for very specific situations.

Like in my **navbar** I am using `dropMenu` tag for a dropdown menu.

```
<b:navBar brand="Brand" brandHref="#" fluid="true">
  <b:navbarLinks pull="right" styleClass="hidden-xs">

    <b:dropMenu value="Dropdown">
      <b:navLink value="Action" href="#"></b:navLink>
      <b:navLink value="Another action" href="#"></b:navLink>
    </b:dropMenu>

  </b:navbarLinks>
</b:navBar>
```

And this renders alomost like [image: This]

But I dont want the down (or up caret) right to the *Dropdown* text.

I have checked **BootsFaces** documentation about [DropMenu](https://showcase.bootsfaces.net/layout/navbars.jsf). Only thing I finds there is `down` option that actually doesn't help about this. Does anyone have any idea how can I remove this from *dropMenu*? Any CSS or anything I have missed from **BootsFaces** ?

Comment: try `.caret { display:none; }`

Comment: oww.. thats a good one. you can put it in answer. It works for me.

Answer (score 2):

I went through the [BootsFaces Documentation](https://showcase.bootsfaces.net/layout/navbars.jsf) and found that the dropdown icon has `caret` class to it.

Hence the following worked in this case :)

```
.caret{
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

After pondering this question for a week, I've decided not to implement a dedicated BootsFaces feature. The CSS rule does the trick. It even works if you want to show or hide the caret depending on a breakpoint. Just add a media query to it.

For the reference: there's also a ticket in the [BootsFaces bug tracker](https://github.com/TheCoder4eu/BootsFaces-OSP/issues/934).

Comment: @Rauh I got your point. Actually, I reported the bug. But what was my concern is as you already added the `drop` option there and the options are `down` and `up`, isn't it more intuitive to have another option `none` to this. when I was first using it, I was so sure about it there must be some option like that, but later I find, no there is not. Maybe you could rename the `drop` option to `drop-icon`. That will make more sense then.

Comment: And think about it, why are we using bootsfaces? Its because we don't bother about layout and styling in front-end. Its a great library that helps us lifting that burden work. So there should be enough support to customize the styling natively.

Comment: Recently I saw a similar feature request to show or hide the caret depending on the screen size. IMHO, that makes a lot of sense. But: that amounts to adding four new attributes (or five, with BS4). That's why I'm reluctant.